# How to refresh listview when click delete button

Tags: android, android-listview, refresh

I have delete coding in **adapter class** as below:

```
delBtn=(ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.del_btn);  
delBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        sqlCon.deleteItem(id);          
    }
});
```

and here is the code in **sqliteconnection class**,

```
public void deleteItem(long id) {
    System.out.println("DELETE ");
    db = sqlHp.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(ItemDb.TABLE, "_id="+id , null);
    db.close();
}
```

How can I refresh the listview when click the **delete** button? Thanks.

**EDIT**
**In class A**

```
 public Cursor getAllItem(String user) {

    String[] userID = new String[] {user};


    db = sqlHp.getReadableDatabase();       
    cur=db.query(ItemDb.TABLE, null, "user=?", userID, null, null, "name");     
    return cur;

}

public Cursor getOneItem(long id) {
    db = sqlHp.getReadableDatabase();
    cur=db.query(ItemDb.TABLE, null, "_id="+ id, null, null, null,null);
    return cur;
}
```

**The class C:**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

        String[] from = new String[] { ItemDb.NAME, ItemDb.CONDITION, ItemDb.EMAIL};
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.etItemName, R.id.etItemCondition, R.id.etEmail };
        itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(this,R.layout.list_item, null, from, to);
        this.setListAdapter(itemAdapter);

        UserName = (String) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("UserName");

        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString("UserName", UserName); // here string is the value you want to save
        editor.commit();                  
        Log.i(Tag, "UserName1: "+ UserName);
    }
```

another part of Class C

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        new GetItem().execute((Object[]) null);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Cursor cursor = itemAdapter.getCursor();

        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.deactivate();

        itemAdapter.changeCursor(null); 
        super.onStop();

    }

    private class GetItem extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Cursor> {
        ItemSQLiteConnector dbConnector = new ItemSQLiteConnector(ItemActivity.this);

        @Override
        protected Cursor doInBackground(Object... params) {
            return dbConnector.getAllItem(UserName);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
            itemAdapter.changeCursor(result);           
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_item, menu);      
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {       
        Intent addItem = new Intent(ItemActivity.this, AddEditItem.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        startActivity(addItem);     
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

}
```

Class B:

```
public class ItemAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    private int layout;
    private ImageButton editBtn;
    private ImageButton delBtn;
    ImageButton addBtn;
    String selection, UserName;
    LayoutInflater inflator;
    final ItemAdapter myadapter = this;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;



    public ItemAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to,0);
        this.layout = layout;
        inflator= LayoutInflater.from(context);


    }

    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {     
        View v = inflator.inflate(layout, parent, false);       
        return v;

    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View v, final Context context, Cursor c) {
        final int id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(ItemDb.ID));
        final String user = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ItemDb.USER));
        final String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ItemDb.NAME));
        final String condition = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ItemDb.CONDITION));
        final String email = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ItemDb.EMAIL));
        final String category = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ItemDb.CATEGORY));
        final byte[] image = c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex(ItemDb.IMAGE));
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.photo);

        if (image != null) {
            if (image.length > 3) {
                iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0,image.length));
            }
        }

        TextView tname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        tname.setText(name);
        TextView tcondition = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.condition);
        tcondition.setText(condition);
        TextView temail = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.email);
        temail.setText(email);



        final ItemSQLiteConnector sqlCon = new ItemSQLiteConnector(context);

        editBtn=(ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.edit_btn);    
        editBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(context, AddEditItem.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);               
                intent.putExtra("id", id);
                intent.putExtra("user", user);
                intent.putExtra("name", name);
                intent.putExtra("condition", condition);
                intent.putExtra("email", email);
                intent.putExtra("category", category);
                intent.putExtra("blob", image);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }

        });

        delBtn=(ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.del_btn);  
        delBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sqlCon.deleteItem(id);      
                //Cursor cur=db.query(ItemDb.TABLE, null, "_id="+ id, null, null, null,null);   
                //myadapter.changeCursor(cur);
                //myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                //Intent intent=new Intent(context,Tab.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                //context.startActivity(intent);        
            }

        });     


        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent=new Intent(context,ViewItem.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);               
                intent.putExtra("id", id);
                intent.putExtra("user", user);
                intent.putExtra("name", name);
                intent.putExtra("condition", condition);
                intent.putExtra("email", email);
                intent.putExtra("category", category);
                intent.putExtra("blob", image);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class ItemAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

private int layout;
private ImageButton editBtn;
private ImageButton delBtn;
ImageButton addBtn;
String selection, UserName;
LayoutInflater inflator;
final ItemAdapter myadapter = this;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private OnItemDeleted mOnItemDeleted;

public interface OnItemDeleted {
    public void updateCursor();
}

public ItemAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
                    String[] from, int[] to, OnItemDeleted onItemDeleted) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to,0);
    this.layout = layout;
    mOnItemDeleted = onItemDeleted;
    inflator= LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

.........

delBtn=(ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.del_btn);  
    delBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sqlCon.deleteItem(id);      
            mOnItemDeleted.updateCursor();

            //Intent intent=new Intent(context,Tab.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            //context.startActivity(intent);        
        }

    }); 
}
```

In the calling class C

```
itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(this,R.layout.list_item, null, from, to, new MyOnItemDeleted());
......
public class MyOnItemDeleted implements ItemAdapter.OnItemDeleted
{
    public void updateCursor()
    {
                 new GetItem().execute((Object[]) null);
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, may I know how to "requery the database and then call changeCursor" ? @Hoan

Comment: Same query as you pass to the adapter. And then adapter.changeCursor(c); where c is the result of the query.

Comment: do you mind to show me the example? Cause when I use **myadapter.changeCursor(c);** but it fail to refresh when I done delete. @Hoan

Comment: Post your code to query the cursor c pass to the ItemAdapter.

Comment: Posted the code. I use

    Cursor cur=db.query(ItemDb.TABLE, null, "_id="+ id, null, null, null,null); 
        myadapter.changeCursor(cur);  

but getting error in logcat and forced close.

Comment: Post the database method that you pass a cursor to your adapter when you initialize the adapter. I think it is getAllItems but you edited your post so I am not sure.

Comment: Sorry, cause I'm not sure which cursor I should pass. Edited, I post two cursor there.

Comment: I need the code that you set your adapter, can you post activity B onCreate code.

Comment: I post the full code for Activity B, but there have no onCreate() in Activity B.@@

Comment: Ok, you would have an activity that have a list which use ItemAdapter. Can you post that activity onCreate. With your class ItemAdapter design right now you cannot update your list at all.

Comment: Posted the class C onCreate().

Comment: Ok, I see you pass null for the param Cursor c. So in the beginning your list is empty, where did you make the change so this param is not null and what is the code.

Comment: Ok, you have to call new GetItem().execute((Object[]) null); after sqlCon.deleteItem(id); this is what I mean by requery. You also call change cursor on postExecute so you do not need to call change cursor again.

Comment: Sorry, may I know how to call GetItem().execute((Object[]) null);>.<

Comment: But I get the error of "GetItem cannot be resolved to a type". Should I create class GetItem in Class B?

Comment: Is GetItem an inner class of C? if so can you make it into separate class then you can use it in ItemAdapter class. You need to make the contructor of ItemAdapter to have a String userName so you can pass in the userName needed in GetItem.

Comment: Yes. GetItem is an inner class of C. But I have no idea how to make it separate and also make the constructor of ItemAdapter to have a String userName. Too complicated and difficult for me. T^T

Comment: By the way, can you have a look in this post too. I have no idea how to solve this problem. T^T
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907038/reading-values-from-one-database-and-write-it-to-another-database

Comment: The easy way for you to use GetItem is to make ItemAdapter an inner class of C. This is not modular but unless you use ItemAdapter in some other class this is OK.

Comment: The database is local, isn't it? If so, is it so large that you have to use asynctask to query?

Comment: The ItemAdapter had used in some other class. @@

Comment: Yes, the database is local sqlite. I need to store many image. Actually this coding I take from online tutorial. http://vimaltuts.com/android-tutorials/android-load-image-from-sqlite-to-listview
I'm just beginner so I study from modify coding to suitable in my case, so some tutorial code still very complicated for me. It is hard for me to modify. Sorry, i'm noob. >.<

Comment: In this case you have to pass in a callback and let the calling class requery. I will edit the answer.

Comment: YES!! FINALLY IT'S WORK!! Thanks for you to spend so many time to solve my problems. Thanks sooo much!! =DDD @Hoan

Comment: Can you give me suggestion how to solve this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907038/reading-values-from-one-database-and-write-it-to-another-database? Stuck in there and no idea how to continue.>.<

Comment: I make a comment there, answer the comment and we go from there.

Answer (score 4):

call `notifyDataSetChanged()` (from the adapter object or within the adapter class) after the delete of the sql and removing the item from the adapter.

Example:

```
WhateverMyAdapterClassIs myadapter = new WhateverMyAdapterClassIs();

...

delBtn=(ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.del_btn);  
delBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
          sqlCon.deleteItem(id);

          //Add code to remove the respective item from the List,ArrayList 
          //or whatever you use in the adapter then call notifyDataSetChanged()

          myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }

});
```

Or if you have extended an adapter class add a removeItem function and call the `notifyDataSetChanged` from it:

```
public void removeItem(int index) {
    myList.remove(index);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

In your case use:

```
final ItemAdapter myadapter = this;

delBtn=(ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.del_btn);  
delBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
          sqlCon.deleteItem(id);

          //Add code to remove the respective item from the List,ArrayList 
          //or whatever you use in the adapter then call notifyDataSetChanged()

          myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }

});
```

Comment: where should I put the WhateverMyAdapterClassIs myadapter = new WhateverMyAdapterClassIs();?

i edited my question.

Comment: Edited my answer, the last case would be the one you use

Comment: This method din't getting error but don't why it still cannot refresh the listview when I clcik the delete button.

Comment: Are you removing the view that is associated with the sql item you are deleting from the List, arraylist or whatever else you use for your adapter before calling notfiyDataSetChanged like the comment in the code tells you?

Comment: sorry, i'm newbie, I can't understand what mean by "remove the respective item from the List,ArrayList or whatever you use in the adapter" so I din't add any code in there.

So what code I should add in there? Sorry, I really not understand.><

Comment: Read http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html it also has a article on implementing your own adapter for the ListView.

Comment: i had edited my question coding, it is I need to remove newView or bindView? since I din't use ArrayList<String> list as mention in the article given. @Patrick Evans