# Reading values from one database and write it to another database

Tags: java, android, methods

I have two method in **SQLiteConnection** class, which is

```
public void UserA(String user, String name, String email, byte[] blob){};
```

and

```
public void UserB(String user, String name, String email, byte[] blob){};
```

I want to combine the value that get in this two method, pass it the third method which use to store in sqlite database.

```
public void TwoUser(String user1, String name1, String email1, byte[] blob1, String user2, String name2, String email2, byte[] blob2){};
```

But I don't know how to access the value(String user, String name, String email, byte[] blob) that I get in **UserA()**, and use it in **TwoUser()**.

What method can be use to get the value in **UserA()**, and use it in **TwoUser()**.

Or is it possible I save the UserA in TwoUser database first, when I get the data from UserB then update the TwoUser database? Mean separate save the data under same column? Is it possible?

**EDIT**

My project is use for swap item, firstly all user need to upload their item so I saved item data in the database as show below.

Next userA will choose the item from UserB, so finally I want to store both item data in new database show I can so the result so swapping.

Here is the database that used to store the different user data.

[image]

That is the result I want, upper one show the UserA item detail, below is the Swap result from UserA and UserB.

[image]

```
public void insertItem(String user, String name, String condition, String email, String category,byte[] blob) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(ItemDb.USER, user);
        cv.put(ItemDb.NAME, name);
        cv.put(ItemDb.CONDITION, condition);
        cv.put(ItemDb.EMAIL, email);
        cv.put(ItemDb.CATEGORY, category);      
        cv.put(ItemDb.IMAGE,blob);


        db = sqlHp.getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(ItemDb.TABLE, null, cv);
        db.close();
    }
```

Comment: save the values in public class variables?

Comment: how to save the values in public class variables?

Comment: I suggest that you create a `User` class to help reduce the redundant code.

Comment: don't know how to reduce the redundant code, i'm newbie.>.<

Comment: Why do you create 2 databases?

Comment: Actually first database is used for stored only user item detail, I think it can't show two user item in one time (mean shown in same row as I shown in xml) so I have an idea to create a new database to store both user swap item in the new database so I can read it and show the swap result.

Comment: Actually what I want is when the userA click the item belong with userB to swap, it will show the swap information in both user profile. The best is can show the notification to inform userB, userA was request to swap the item, but I totally no idea about sending notification. So i try change to show swap result in both user profile. I think it will easier.

Comment: No you can show two users item in one time using the same database. Anyway let me try to understand what you want to do first.

Comment: I see. Ok, take your time and thanks in advance. ^^

Comment: You want to show a list with userA items and userB items?

Comment: Yes, When userA choose the item for swap then show a the swap result which contain both user item that choosed.

Comment: You only need one database, just post the complete code for UserA(String user, String name, String email, byte[] blob).

Comment: Posted. Actually those data I get and save in database when user choose the add item in profile.

Comment: So UserA is just insertItem, UserB should be the same method, what do you want with TwoUser?

Comment: You are right. In my idea is I wan TwoUser database to show the swap result in both user profile. The swap result contain both user choosed item detail that same in one row as I xml shown. Do you understand what I mean?>.<

Comment: So user A wants to swap with user B, you want to store the swap info until user B approves and then switch the swap items?

Comment: Actually this three method I post still just a idea for me to progress the next step. I plan to get the first UserA paticular selected item data and put in UserA method, then next step to get the particular selected data to put in UserB method, so finially I can get the data in both method and stored it in TwoUser method. SO I can read the database and show the swap result in both user profile, it is my idea.

Comment: Or do you need me to email you my project so you can try and understand what I want? But it is not completed yet.

Comment: Ok email me, it is almost 2AM here and I am going to sleep.

Comment: Opss.. I'm sorry. My here is 4++PM. I will email and hope you can more clear for what I mean. Thanks and have a sweet dream. ^^

Comment: Hi, @HoanNguyen any suggestion for this part?

Answer (score 1):

It's a redudancy method you're using above, UserA and UserB have same parameter (and same function maybe).
If I were you, I would make it like (one method only):

```
public void user(String user[], String name[], String email[], byte blob[]){

  String user1=user[0], user2=user[1];  
  String name1=name[0], name2=name[1];
  String email1=email[0], email2=email[1];
  byte blob1=blob[0], blob2=blob[1];

  //What to do next

}
```

Comment: but I get the data from different class, so I need to separate into two class. Mean Activity A pass me the UserA data, Activity B pass me the UserB data, and I want to combine both User data in Activity C which is used to store in TwoUser database.

Comment: I suggest you should make the variable global in both class A and B, the use getter to retrieve the variable in each class.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new in Java and android, can't understanding what mean by   "make the variable global in both class A and B, the use getter to retrieve the variable in each class". Do you mind to show me some example?

Comment: you can store the data into an `Intent` when starting a new activity. In the new activity you can retrieve the data that was passed with it. Also, you can try using `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: Try this link out: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html it provides `Java` tutorials and will help you learn and understand `Java` and Object-oriented programming

Comment: So there are no method can direct access the data in UserA()? Since I put this three method in same java class.

Comment: Hm, you're starting to confuse me hhehe. You have all the 3 methods in 1 class (Main class perharp), and you want to retrieve the data from another class and store them in your Main class, is that right?

Comment: yes. Actually the UserA and UserB data are saved in same database, but I want to retrieve those data and save it in new databse which is TwoUser, so I can show two User data under same row in listview.

Comment: If it's a database, all you need is a ResultSet to read the data from UserA and UserB database. And then write it to TwoUser database. And your question title will better come to __Reading values from one database and write it to another database__ :)

Comment: I'm sorry. Maybe I had confuse your all. But I'm poor in programming as well as English. I think I need to edit my question first.. >.<

Comment: Go ahead and edit your question, we will help you as best as we could :)

Comment: Is it swapping all the data?

Comment: what you mean by swapping all the data? It is swap the item, but I just want to show what item of UserA and UserB are swapped.

Comment: which item to swap is it? how do you choose the item to swap?

Comment: I have one category list, so the user can choose the item that they want to swap from category list. I added the xml in my question.

Comment: T_T sorry but I still don't understand what you want, especially when it comes to Android, I haven't study android yet..

Comment: It's okay. Thanks for your effort for try to help me. Appreciate it. Thanks =D